# Number of conjugacy classes of a cyclic subgroup

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations, symmetric-groups

Let $G=S_{15}$ (symmetric group on $15$ symbols). We say that any two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ are conjugate if $gHg^{-1}=K$ for some $g\in G$.  This is an equivalence relation and the equivalence classes are known as conjugate classes. Find the number of conjugacy classes of cyclic subgroup of order $15$ in $S_{15}$.

I know that any two elements in $S_n$ are conjugate if they have the same cyclic structure. Is there any such result to determine the conjugacy classes for subgroups? Please help.

Comment: No. I am looking for subgroups, not for elements.

Comment: A cyclic group of order 15 is generated by an element of order 15, which is necessarily the product of a 3-cycle and a disjoint 5-cycle, or a 15-cycle.  The two cases are necessarily non-conjugate (think about fixed points). Count the number of elements of each type, and then be careful about distinct elements yielding the same sungroup.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The  number of $15$-cycles are $14!$ and $(3, 5)$-cycles are $\frac{15!}{5!\times 3!}$.  How to think forward?

Comment: How many 15-cycles generate the same cyclic group? how many 3-5 cycles?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin 
This is given by Euler's function that is $\phi(15)=8$.

Comment: So then you can count the number of subgroups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes. The number of subgroups because of $15$ cycles are $\frac{14!}{8}$ and that of $(3,5)$ cycles are $\frac{15!}{8!\times 3!\times 8}$.

Comment: I gave you the hints. I don't need a blow-by-blow report of your progress.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I thought with my blow-by-blow report, you are taking me to the answer. Anyway, I thank you very much.

Comment: You **have** the answer. And you aren't asking any questions. You are just pinging me to inform me of your progress. To what end? None.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am sorry for pinging you many times. This is one last time. Can you please tell me how to proceed forward because I really don't understand how to get only $5$ conjugacy classes out of these many subgroups.

Comment: Any two 15 cycles are conjugate, so the subgroups they generate are conjugate. Any rwo 3-5 cycles are conjugate, so the subgroups they generate are conjugate. Don't know where you get 5 conjugacy classes...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Is it that all the cycles $(15), (3, 5), (3, 3, 5), (3, 3, 3, 5), (3, 5, 5)$  (total $5$) generate cyclic subgroups of order $15$? Am I right?